# Why is this query being logged as "not using indexes"?

Tags: mysql, database-performance

For some reason my slow query log is reporting the following query as "not using indexes" and for the life of me I cannot understand why.

Here is the query:

```
update  scheduletask
set     active = 0
where   nextrun < date_sub( now(), interval 2 minute )
and     enabled = 1
and     active = 1;
```

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `scheduletask` (
  `scheduletaskid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `schedulethreadid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `taskname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `taskpath` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `tasknote` text,
  `recur` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `taskinterval` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastrunstart` datetime NOT NULL,
  `lastruncomplete` datetime NOT NULL,
  `nextrun` datetime NOT NULL,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `creatorid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `editorid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `edited` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`scheduletaskid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Name` (`taskname`),
  KEY `IDX_NEXTRUN` (`nextrun`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Get explain and post the result here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another index like this

```
KEY `IDX_COMB` (`nextrun`, `enabled`, `active`)
```

I'm not sure how many rows your table have but the following might apply as well

> Sometimes MySQL does not use an index, even if one is available. One
>   circumstance under which this occurs is when the optimizer estimates
>   that using the index would require MySQL to access a very large
>   percentage of the rows in the table. (In this case, a table scan is
>   likely to be much faster because it requires fewer seeks.)

Answer (score 0):

try using the "explain" command in mysql. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html
I think explain only works on select statements, try:

explain select * from scheduletask where nextrun < date_sub( now(), interval 2 minute ) and enabled = 1 and active = 1;

Maybe if you use, nextrun = ..., it will macht the key IDX_NEXTRUN. In your where clause has to be one of your keys, scheduletaskid, taskname or nextrun

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the short answer but I don't have time to write a complete solution.

I believe you can fix your issue by saving `date_sub( now(), interval 2 minute )` in a temporary variable before using it in the query, see here maybe: [MySql How to set a local variable in an update statement (Syntax?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475311/mysql-how-to-set-a-local-variable-in-an-update-statement-syntax).

Comment: How does that help MySQL to use proper index?