# Customized cyclic number design in database

Tags: mysql

I need a database design (**mysql 8.0+**) to support a cyclic number series from 1 to a specific max number, such as 1 to 3, then would be get `1,2,3,1,2,3,...` as query result respectively and cyclically. My version has been worked successfully but hope seeking for maybe better, native version. Many thanks.

My scripts are here,

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cyclic_series_number` (
  `category` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `sn` int NOT NULL,
  `max` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category`)
);
```

Afterwards, insert 2 records. The 1st record will be the one to test.

```sql
REPLACE INTO `cyclic_series_number` (`category`, `sn`, `max`) 
VALUES ('testing', 1, 3), ('ticket', 1, 999);

SELECT * FROM `cyclic_series_number`;
+--------------------------+
|   cyclic_series_number   |
+---+-----------+----+-----+
| # |  category | sn | max |
+---+-----------+----+-----+
| 1 | 'testing' | 1  |  3  |
+---+-----------+----+-----+
| 2 |  'ticket' | 1  | 999 |
+---+-----------+----+-----+
```

The last, offering a stored procedure.

> *The idea is to update (sn=sn+1) and get that number as well as a necessary check sn+1 to see if exceeds the max number.*
>
> *All above logics run at the same time.*

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `get_new_sn`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE get_new_sn(IN input_category varchar(100))
BEGIN
    SET @latest_sn = -1;
    UPDATE `cyclic_series_number`
    SET `sn` = (@latest_sn := case `sn` when `max` then 1 else `sn` + 1 end)
    WHERE `category` = @input_category;

    SELECT @latest_sn;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

The testing result shows the stored procedure works.

```sql
CALL get_new_sn('testing'); -- 2
CALL get_new_sn('testing'); -- 3
CALL get_new_sn('testing'); -- 1
CALL get_new_sn('testing'); -- 2
CALL get_new_sn('testing'); -- 3
CALL get_new_sn('testing'); -- 1
-- ...
```

References

- StackOverflow [mysql-how-to-set-a-local-variable-in-an-update-statement-syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475311/mysql-how-to-set-a-local-variable-in-an-update-statement-syntax)

Comment: Is it mysql or SQL Server (the product from Microsoft)? If the latter, there are first-class sequence objects that do what you want natively (with the cycling). If that's what you're working with, I'll write it up.

Comment: @BenThul **mysql** please, many thanks ~

Comment: I suggest you simplify the problem; so numbers run from 1 to 5, say. Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry totally agree, so actually I've simplified that from 999,999 to 99. guess it's clear already, isn't it ?

Comment: No. See above .

Comment: @BenThul Hi, I've updated and simplified the question. May I have any hint for the way more natively ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE sourcetable
SET sourcetable.num = subquery.num
FROM ( SELECT id, 1 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) - 1) % 99 num
       FROM sourcetable ) subquery
WHERE sourcetable.id = subquery.id;
```

where 99 is upper limit.

Comment: I struggle to imagine a situation where this would be useful

Comment: @Akina thanks, but do you have the version for **mysql** ? And why update from a subquery ? Looks that must be careful if `sourcetable` is not a small table.

Comment: @nwpie You have not specified MySQL version - so I may assume that you use the most recent version. *And why update from a subquery ?* This is simple - both in logic and in SQL text. You may use any another technique, no problems. *if sourcetable is not a small table.* I hope there is primary key (`id` in my code) or at least unique index in the table?

Comment: @Akina Earlier post I should not have put double tags for `mysql` and `sql-server`, Now removed `sql-server` already. Sorry that's my mistake.

Comment: What version of mysql are you using? The features in this answer require 8 or later.

Comment: Yes mysql 8.0+ .

Answer (score 0):

keeping your stored procedure...

change line that starts:
SET `sn` = (@latest_sn := case `sn` when ... .. ...

to something like:
SET `sn` = (`sn` + 1) % `max`;

The modulo operator returns remainder after division...  so if sn+1 is less than max then the remainder is sn+1.  Once sn+1 = max, remainder = 0 and it starts over...   This means too,  that max needs to be 1 higher than highest allowed value...  so if sn can be 99 but not 100, then max = 100.

Comment: Thanks, `MOD` operator is more clear. Though we don't allow sn is zero, this formula you mentioned would change to `sn = (sn % max) + 1`. Thus guarantee no zero returned.